# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Guid'

Tags: sql-server, .net

Desde sqlserver estoy tratando de recibir una columna que es de tipo int identity

Código en SQLServer:

```
Id int not null identity
```

y guardarla en una variable con el siguiente casting:

```
Id = (Guid)respuesta["Id"]
```

Donde en mi modelo, el atributo Id es de tipo Guid

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

Y me sale el siguiente error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Guid'
```

Comment: y si..si son de tipos totalmente y diametralmente opuestos, que esperas hacer?

Comment: @gbianchi no sabía que eran de tipos totalmente y diametralmente opuestos, ni se qué es eso, esa fue la solución que me arrojó el visual studio, pero no me funciona. Qué propones tu como solución?

Comment: Leiste que es un guid??? la solucion de VS es standard a lo que hay que hacer para transformar un tipo en otro.. no quiere decir que sea "transformable".. un guid es esto: A GUID (globally unique identifier) is a 128-bit text string that represents an identification (ID).... ahora como transformas un int en eso?